# How to fetch last 24 hour record using unix timestamps

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, unix-timestamp

I have following two tables in MySQL and I want to get name and count of reviews. How can I do this?

Here is my table `un_users`:

```
id      wallet_address          username    
1       xxxxxxxxxxxxxx          abc
2       xxxxxxxxxxxxxx          xyz
3       xxxxxxxxxxxxxx          def
4       xxxxxxxxxxxxxx          jkl
```

Here is my table `coin_review`:

```
id      wallet_address      review                  review_creation_time
1       xxxxxxxxxxxxx       Lorem Ipsum1            1632812650  
2       xxxxxxxxxxxxx       Lorem Ipsum2            1632812211
3       xxxxxxxxxxxxx       Lorem Ipsum3            1632812650
4       xxxxxxxxxxxxx       Lorem Ipsum4            1632814574
```

I tried with following code but not working:

```
SELECT u.username, COUNT(c.Review) AS totalreview
FROM un_users u
LEFT JOIN coin_review c ON c.wallet_address = u.wallet_address
GROUP BY u.username
ORDER BY u.username
```

I want to know how can I get "last 24 hours" records?

Comment: Sample data is great, but you also need to specify the expected result.

Comment: The error message is quite clear. You either need to add u.id and u.username to the GROUP BY, _or_ have these columns as arguments to set functions.

Comment: @jarlh: let me update question , i missed one column

Comment: @amit do you want 0 counts too (i.e. users with 0 revires in 24 hours)?

Comment: @SalmanA: no i dont want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that review_creation_time is a unix timestamp, you can use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` function to compare apples to apples:

```sql
SELECT
    u.id, u.wallet_address, u.username,
    COUNT(c.id) AS review_count
FROM un_users u
JOIN coin_review c ON c.wallet_address = u.wallet_address
WHERE c.review_creation_time >  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
AND   c.review_creation_time <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
GROUP BY u.id
```

Comment: i updated my question , please check

Comment: giving me empty result

Comment: its working now,Thanks :)